Why my lineart are visible when i'm looking for behind the object?
How to fix the it?
Here's the .blend file ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/12LxFHE3bhb_hLMjB4thCQHZUDCv13onA/view?usp=sharing )



In the Object Properties under Viewport Display, you have In Front enabled for the Line Art objects.

